# Elixir app runs in iex, but need to add :eex as a dependency to run as a release

Tags: elixir, release, dependency-management

I've created a simple Cowboy/Plug application that uses `Plug.Debugger`.

These are my runtime dependencies in `mix.exs`

```
extra_applications: [:cowboy, :plug, :logger]
```

I am using Distillery via `mix release` to produce a release.

Both `iex -S mix` and running the release start the application fine, but they differ when an error occurs. For the `iex` session, `Debugger` correctly handles errors, but for the release, I get the following error:

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function EEx.Engine.fetch_assign!/2 is undefined (module EEx.Engine is not available)`

I'm assuming EEx is used by `Plug.Debugger` to format the output.

I can fix this by adding `:eex` to `extra_applications` in `mix.exs`, rebuilding the release and re-running.

Why does `:eex` need to be listed as a dependency to run as part of a release, but not when run from `iex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir runtime [adds some internal applications](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ad01452787d5428bed2bbeae9869ad542d04e221/lib/iex/lib/iex/introspection.ex#L216) to OTP:

```
 @elixir_apps ~w(eex elixir ex_unit iex logger mix)a
```

One also can do `Logger.log` from the `iex` console etc. The OTP runtime, that is built by Distillery *does not include these applications*.